# MDX Query Row Count

Tags: mdx, rowcount

I'm a newbie to MDX Querying. I'm trying to create a row number for the follwing query, but for the life of me am lost...

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY 
{ 
[Measures].[Bench], [Measures].[Act] 
} ON COLUMNS, 

NON EMPTY 
{ 
([dim1].[Attr Period].[Attr Period].ALLMEMBERS ) 
} 

DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
MEMBER_CAPTION, 
MEMBER_VALUE, 
MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME 
ON ROWS 

FROM 
[Cubex]
```

Can anyone help me add a Row Number to the output?
Right now I get:

```html
ATTR PERIOD   bench        act
2016_q1       $10,000.00   $11,000.00 
2016_q2       $10,000.00   $11,000.00 
2016_q3       $10,000.00   $11,000.00 
2016_q4       $10,000.00   $11,000.00 
2017_q1       $10,000.00   $11,000.00 
2017_q2       $10,000.00   $11,000.00 
2017_q3       $10,000.00   $11,000.00 
2017_q4       $10,000.00   $11,000.00
```

I want:

```html
row   ATTR PERIOD   bench        act
1     2016_q1       $10,000.00   $11,000.00 
2     2016_q2       $10,000.00   $11,000.00 
3     2016_q3       $10,000.00   $11,000.00 
4     2016_q4       $10,000.00   $11,000.00 
5     2017_q1       $10,000.00   $11,000.00 
6     2017_q2       $10,000.00   $11,000.00 
7     2017_q3       $10,000.00   $11,000.00 
8     2017_q4       $10,000.00   $11,000.00
```

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to add row number to scripts myself using MDX but did not find a solution.

MDX nearly always feeds into a client e.g SSRS, better you add your row number using functionality of the client.